# app shows stretched app icon instead of launch image when launching from local notification

Tags: iphone, ios

If it is launched by tapping on it, it will display its launch image before displaying the first view controller, as normal.

Now, my app generates local notifications at regular intervals. If the app is not active and the user taps the notification, the app launches. I am expecting it to display its launch image just before displaying the first view controller, as other apps do when launched from a notification. But just before showing the first view controller, my app shows its app icon (stretched to fill the screen) instead of showing the launch image.

- The icon file (`icon.png`) is **not** mentioned anywhere in my code.
- I tried setting `Default.png` as the value of `UILaunchImageFile` in my Info.plist file, it didn't make a difference.

Why is it not displaying the launch image?

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the local notification? The error may be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you are setting the [*alertLaunchImage*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/alertLaunchImage) property of the local notification object correctly. You can specify here the image that you want to show as launch image when the user opens the application using the notification. You can set it to `nil` to show the App default splash screen.

Comment: I also had to delete the icon files and launch screen files (several times), and renamed `icon.png` to `Icon.png` (apparently [it's a requirement](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html)).

Comment: The icon name is not a requirement. It's the icon itself what it's a requirement. You can specify the name that you wish as long as you include it in the application PList (see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW10).